# Is there a way to login into the application through Keycloak programmatically using cypress/JS?

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, keycloak, cypress

I writing automated tests in Cypress for a web application that is protected by Keycloak. I have managed to retrieve the jwt token from keycloak, but I don't know what to do with it. I have seen that after you login into keycloak, you are redirected to your domain and keyclock sets cookies, local storage, etc.
Is there a way to get the same results programmatically as keyclock does when you login in their page? With other words, have something like:

```js
cy.getToken().then((token) => {
   cy.login(token);
   cy.visit(myDomain)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at libraries, [cypress-keycloak-commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-keycloak-commands) is another one, more popular (around three time the weekly downloads).

I like the way it is configuration-based, and has `cy.kcFakeLogin()` for fixture-based mocks.

There is also this blog [Cypress.io Keycloak Integration](https://vrockai.github.io/blog/2017/10/28/cypress-keycloak-intregration/) if you want to learn the details of Keycloak.

Reproduced for future reference if the link disappears

```
Cypress.Commands.add('kcLogin', (username, password) => {
  const kcRoot = 'http://my.keycloak.com';
  const kcRealm = 'MYrealm';
  const kcClient = 'my-client';
  const kcRedirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/';
  const loginPageRequest = {
    url: `${kcRoot}/auth/realms/${kcRealm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth`,
    qs: {
      client_id: kcClient,
      redirect_uri: kcRedirectUri,
      state: createUUID(),
      nonce: createUUID(),
      response_mode: 'fragment',
      response_type: 'code',
      scope: 'openid'
    }
  };
  // Open the KC login page, fill in the form with username and password and submit.
  return cy.request(loginPageRequest)
    .then(submitLoginForm);
  ////////////
  function submitLoginForm(response) {
    const _el = document.createElement('html');
    _el.innerHTML = response.body;
    // This should be more strict depending on your login page template.
    const loginForm = _el.getElementsByTagName('form');
    const isAlreadyLoggedIn = !loginForm.length;
    if (isAlreadyLoggedIn) {
      return;
    }
    return cy.request({
      form: true,
      method: 'POST',
      url: loginForm[0].action,
      followRedirect: false,
      body: {
        username: username,
        password: password        
      }
    });
  }
  // Copy-pasted code from KC javascript client. It probably doesn't need to be 
  // this complicated but I refused to spend time on figuring that out.
  function createUUID() {
    var s = [];
    var hexDigits = '0123456789abcdef';
    for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
      s[i] = hexDigits.substr(Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x10), 1);
    }
    s[14] = '4';
    s[19] = hexDigits.substr((s[19] & 0x3) | 0x8, 1);
    s[8] = s[13] = s[18] = s[23] = '-';
    var uuid = s.join('');
    return uuid;
  }
});
```

Comment: I have also tried this plugin with no luck. It just doesn't get me logged in. And also you need to edit the code for this one, "const loginForm = _el.getElementsByTagName('form'); " this didn't work. I had to take the url from this form in another way. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Oh, BTW [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) is `getElementsByTagName()`, it should be built into your browser.

Comment: Actually is part of JS and yes it is recognized by the browser, it just couldn't find the tag('form') even if it was present. So I had to find the form in another way.

Comment: Ok, yeah consider the blog code a starting point, obviously needs more error checking. At least it's grass-roots and pretty easy to debug (logging the response, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plugin [cypress-keycloak](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-keycloak) to achieve this.

After installing go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and write:

```
// Using ES6
import 'cypress-keycloak';

OR

// using CommonJS
require('cypress-keycloak');
```

Then in your tests you can write (Example taken from cypress-keycloak npm page) :

```
describe('thing', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login({
      root: 'https://keycloak.babangsund.com',
      realm: 'stage',
      username: 'babangsund',
      password: 'bacon',
      client_id: 'frontend',
      redirect_uri: 'https://babangsund.com/',
    });

    // or login with OTP
    cy.loginOTP({
      root: 'https://keycloak.babangsund.com',
      realm: 'stage',
      username: 'babangsund',
      password: 'bacon',
      client_id: 'frontend',
      redirect_uri: 'https://babangsund.com/',
      otp_secret: 'OZLDC2HZKM3QUC...', // e.g. 32 chars
      otp_credential_id: '5e231f20-8ca7-35e1-20a694b60181ca9', // e.g. 36 chars
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.logout({
      root: 'https://keycloak.babangsund.com',
      realm: 'stage',
      redirect_uri: 'https://babangsund.com/',
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for me, it doesn't seems to work. I have tried some other plugins before, but with no luck. Have you tried this plugin and it worked for you? `

Comment: Have you inputted all the values correctly like root, realm, username, password etc. correctly ? Also have you added `require('cypress-keycloak');` under `cypress/support/commands.js` after installing the plugin.

Comment: Yes, I have did everything it says on their website.

Comment: Hi, Alapan Das. It did helped and i can see the things are set into localstorage in test case when i amtryng to navigate cy.visit(`${Cypress.config().baseUrl}/dashboard`) in url it doesn't but manually if i do on same cypress browser instance it does work any help?

Comment: @Boogie how did you resolved this issue any help?

Comment: @khizer Nope, I couldn't find a solution and I didn't want to invest more time. What I did is: do the normal login(from ui) and after each test, save the local storage and at the begining of a new test upload the saved local storage back in the browser. Like this, I don't have to relogin after each test because my session is still valid. Check the following link: https://blog.digital-craftsman.de/keep-local-storage-in-cypress/

Comment: @Boogie thanks alot, i'll try good alternate. Appreciated